# How to get a firebase's database keys and values

Tags: node.js, firebase, discord.js

I'm new to firebase, and I'm doing a database for my discord.js bot. I know how to do almost everything, except i don't know how to get all the db data. Let me explain:

My database structure looks like this:
[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnAqD.png)

And i would like that when executing the showconfig command, it shows something like this:

```js
announcementsChannel: "news",
autoRole: "false",
autoRoleName: "none",
// etc...
```

Is there any way to get every key and its value, and putting it all inside a message?

Answer (score 1):

```js
db.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
   querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
     console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
   });
});
```

You can read the docs online at this link : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart